# Localization in Automapper profile using projections

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, automapper

I have implemented Automapper using projections. I have to use  IStringLocalizer in my profiles but I cannot inject it. I tried to use a resolver (IMemberValueResolver) but this is not compatible with projections.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Luis

I tried using Resolvers but they are not compatible with projections. I need to translate the words Mañana (Tomorrow), Hoy (Today), etc.

This code is working now, using projections. But I would like to use Localization.

```
public ProgrammeDetailEventProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<ProgrammeCheckupEvent, ProgrammeCheckupEventProgressDTO>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Value.Value))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom(x =>
                   GetDate(x.Date, x.Meal)))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.LastUpdate, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.LastUpdate.HasValue ? x.LastUpdate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") : " - "));

            #endregion
        }
        public string GetDate(DateTime date, string meal)
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            string detail = meal != null ? meal.ToLower() : date.ToShortTimeString();
            if (today.AddDays(1) == date.Date)
            {
                return $"Mañana, {detail}";
            }
            else if (today == date.Date)
            {
                return $"Hoy, {detail}";
            }
            else if (today.AddDays(-1) == date.Date)
            {
                return $"Ayer, {detail}";
            }
            return $"{date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")}, {detail}";
        }
```

I expect to have something like this:

```
return string.Format(localizer["Today"], detail);
//Will show in English, "Today [...]"
//Will show in Spanish, "Hoy [...]"
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lucian! I checked what you sent. My problem is that I don't have to just send a parameter but I need to use some data from my source (like the Date and the Start) in order to create the final string that i will assign to Date property in my destination.

Comment: Try writing your query without AM, just use LINQ, and see what happens. ProjectTo runs in the database, so if passing parameters doesn't help, you'll have to use Map instead.